# Return record with maximum value stored as string using Linq to SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am retrieving records that contain information about document versions. The document version number is stored as a string. The format is 8 numeric digits followed by a period followed by four numeric digits (regex ^/d{8}./d{4}$). Numbers stored as text.

I have two functions in my data repository. One called GetAllVersions which returns all records in the version database, and another called GetLatestVersion which should return the record with the maximum version number.

My code looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyProject.Models.Version> GetAllVersions()
{
    var versions = from v in _datacontext.Versions
                   select v;
    return versions;
}
public MyProject.Models.Version GetLatestVersion()
{
    var dataset = GetAllVersions()
                 .Where(x => x.VersionNumber.ToString() == x.VersionNumber.ToString().Max());
    return dataset;
}
```

GetAllVersions works, but I cannot get the Linq to SQL syntax to return the record with the maximum version number. Is there a way to do this in Linq to SQL?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which part of the version number determines if its "the latest" ?

Comment: @Magnus, the whole thing. It's actually just a date and time stamp (yyyymmdd.hhmm). But sometimes we issue a patch and increment the minute up for an older version.

Comment: You should store the value as `DateTime` instead of `varchar` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GetAllVersions().OrderByDescending(x=>x.VersionNumber).First();
```

Comment: I ran a trace to look at the query that Linq to SQL is producing and this seems to work. It even works in cases where the base query already has an order by clause. The second order by clause in Linq to SQL takes the first position in T-SQL making it the dominant sort factor, effectively reordering the query. Thanks Bob!